# how to plugins gwt for eclipse 3.4.x in linux

Tags: linux, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm using eclipse 3.4.1 , I want to install gwt using eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install the Google Plugin for Eclipse (which includes the GWT SDK), see [these instructions](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.4.html).